# Как дать имя подвыражению в регулярных выражениях?

Tags: c#, .net, регулярные-выражения

Есть следующий код (из инфиксной нотации в постфиксную):

```
string infixTerm = "2*3";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(\d+)(\*)(\d+)");
string postfixTerm = reg.Replace(infixTerm, @"$1 $3 $2");
Console.WriteLine(postfixTerm); // ==> 2 3 *
```

Все хорошо, но хотелось бы заменить `$1` на имя `factor1`, а `$2` на `factor2`. Как можно это дело реализовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Всё просто:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(?<factor1>\d+)(?<operator>\*)(?<factor2>\d+)");
string postfixTerm = reg.Replace(infixTerm, @"${factor1} ${factor2} ${operator}");
```

См. [Substitutions in Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx) ([Подстановки в регулярных выражениях](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx)).